# creating a multi-page pdf from a one page template with itextsharp

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, pdf-generation, itext

I have a requirement to generate a multi-page pdf from a template in code behind.
for every entry in my datasource, I basically need to have the template form filled with data from the entry, and then appended to the being generated file

I am assuming i maybe should create the page as a separate PDF document and then use some sort of merge mechanism to append it to the resulting pdf:
1.load pdf template

2.foreach(entry in datasource)

create new page/document from template

fill with data

append to pdf being generated

I am sure someone has had a similar thing to deal with before me! 
I obviously have some reading and research to do but I just thought i'd save me some time by posting here first.

thanks